# How to store List using PostgreSQL in Java Springboot JPA?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to Java related techniques, and I currently working on a SpringBoot Project, and I need to store a list of numbers, such as `'XXXXX':[1,2,3,4...]`, but the result is not what I want.

Here is my entity:

[image]

This is the repository class:

[image]

This is how I save the data in my project:

[image]

And this is the final result that the data store in the database:

[image]

I don't want data stored in such style, cause I may need to get `time_slot_list` using `connectio_id`. It would increase my program complexity. How could I fix it? If there is some information is ambiguity, please let me, I would fix that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How could you fix what? Nothing's broken. Don't use a relational database if you don't like the format it uses, and don't especially use JPA then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to 'fix' something. It's the correct way to store a List for an entity in a relational database. Just take a look at database normalization.
I understand that it might look unnecessary at first but this way is better to work with over all.